# Game reset button not functioning correctly. Un-clickable divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So in this game I am making, there is a restart button that reshuffles the cards, and returns things back to start. The cards reshuffle and replace, but afterwards none are clickable. The class cardClicked is added on click, and removed once two are chosen after a timeout function. Also (not to pile it on), but any good ideas on how to start and reset the timer on start and restart? Thanks.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r9gt39dz/2/)

```
  var cardsArray = [];
  $('.cardClicked').removeClass("cardClicked");
  var moves = [];
  $('.movesBlock').html('<p class="movesText">' + 'Moves: ' + moves.length + '</p>');
  $('.rating').html('Rating:' + starItem + starItem + starItem);
  for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    $('<div class="card"/>').html('<span class="cardText">' + items[i] + '</span>').appendTo('.board');
  };
  items = shuffle(items);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because on `.restart` click you are removing the `.card` from the DOM thats why `$('.card').click()` is not working after `.restart` click...

So  you will need to use ***[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)*** here on `.card` click like

```
$(document).on('click','.card',function(){
  //do stuff here
}
```

And also you had written `$('.card').click()` twice in your code...no need of it. Combine both.

[**Updated Fiddle ▸**](https://jsfiddle.net/bhuwanb9/r9gt39dz/6/)

Comment: Okay. Thanks. Any clue why the moves array isn't emptying on the restart click?

Comment: @Will have you written the code to empty the array in restart click..?

Comment: Yes. It empties it, and sets it back to zero and empty.

Comment: @Will try this `moves = [];` in restart click

Comment: @Will you have written `var moves = []` inside the restart click...there is a difference between `var moves = []` and `moves = []`...

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a function to manage the timer out of the ready function

```
var timer;
function resetTimer() {
  clearInterval(timer);
  var mins = 0;
  var secs = 0;
  timer = window.setInterval(
    function() {
      secs = secs + 1;
      if (secs == 59) {
        mins = mins + 1;
        secs = 0;
      }
      $('.countUp').html('<p>' + 'Timer: ' + mins + ':' + secs + '</p>');
    }, 1000);
 }
```

When you need to start or restart the timer, you just need to call the fucntion `resetTimer();`